# java.lang.NullPointerException ошибка в коде

Tags: java

Не понимаю как исправить эту ошибку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PokladnaApp:

```
private static void pridatZbozi() {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Zadej kod zbozi");
    int kod = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Zadej mnozstvi");
    int mnozstvi = sc.nextInt();
    pokladna.pridejPolozku(kod, mnozstvi); //
}
```

94 ряд это - pokladna.pridejPolozku(kod, mnozstvi);

Цикл Pokladna:

```
public void pridejPolozku(int kodZbozi, int mnozstvi) {
    try {
        for (PolozkaZbozi p : polozkyZbozi) {
            if (kodZbozi == p.getKod()) {
                polozkyZbozi.add(new PolozkaZbozi(p.getKod(),
                        p.getCena(), p.getIdSazbaDPH(), p.getPopis()));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Zkuste znovu");
            }
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
        System.out.println("Zadejte znovu");
    }
    uctenkaMnozstvis.add(new VypisUctenky(mnozstvi));
    /// записать количество
}
```

Comment: И как понять где 94 строка в коде?

Comment: @AntonSorokin, pridatZbozi статический метод, который внутри себя обращается к глобальной для класса переменной **sc**. И скорей всего строка **int mnozstvi = sc.nextInt();** и является этой 94 строкой. Переменная sc не определена на момент вызова, отчего и вылетает эксепшен

Comment: объект **pokladna** на момент вызова **pridejPolozku** чему равен? Null?

Comment: вместо pokladna.pridejPolozku(kod, mnozstvi); напишите new Pokladna.pridejPolozku(kod, mnozstvi);

Comment: @Дмитрий он создает класс pridejPolozku, а мне этого не нужно

Comment: @MiMEKiZ не понимаю ваш вопрос, в PokladnaApp я ввожу данные

Comment: создает , разумется, а как вы без экземпляра класса хотите вызвать нестатический метод?

Comment: @Fleeploed, в 94 строке вы обращаетесь к объекту **pokladna**, который не существует. Вам уже подсказали, что надо написать new Pokladna().pridejPolozku(..). Это создает временный объект. Без создания объекта типа Pokladna вы не сможете обратиться к не статическим методам этого класса. Если вам не надо создавать объект, делайте pridatZbozi не статическим, и из него вызывайте уже this.pridejPolozku(..) или просто pridejPolozku(..).

Comment: кто вообще так переменные называет?

Comment: Знаешь, что такое null pointer exception и с чем его едят?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, вы всего лишь создали ссылку на класс Pokladna (объект pokladna(`pokladna`)), но не указали, куда она должна вести, например она может вести на самого себя: `Pokladna pokladna = new Pokladna();` или его суб-класс, (класс, который наследует наш класс), так же можно скопировать ссылке другой объект, клонировать другой объект (но это уже другая история), не забывая о статическом контексте, но тут он у вас соблюдается(объект класса Pokladna - статический). В итоге, `static Pokladna pokladna;` нужно заменить на `static Pokladna pokladna = new Pokladna();`, либо сделать это внутри метода `pridejPolozku()`, написав `pokladna = new Pokladna();`.